# Create columns in a list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create two columns in an unordered list.  I have been somewhat successful, however, I don't want to specify a width for `ul` and `li span` but instead have it take up all the width of its parent (i.e. `div`).  How should I do this?  Thanks

**CSS**

```
div {
    width:300px;
}
ul {
    width:200px;
}
li span {
    width: 170px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="someName[]"><span>Some short text</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="someName[]"><span>Some very very very very very very long text</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="someName[]"><span>Some short text</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't this what tables are for?

Comment: @ppeterka66.  I don't know.  Seems like I am told differently every time.

Comment: Tables are not _always_ bad. For layout, they are outdated, but there is nothing that would beat them for displaying - well, tables. (and from what you wrote, it occurred to me that you want something very similar, if not identical to that. Sorry, if I did misunderstand you however)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about supporting IE7, you could use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`:

```
li { display: table; }
li > * { display: table-cell }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoGAt

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CSS with

```
div {

}
ul {

}
li span {

    display:inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: That works until the line needs to break which is the whole point.  http://jsfiddle.net/La6rG/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    width:300px;
}
li input { 
    position: absolute; 
}
li span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mn7QS/